# I can't Publish my website anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, visual-web-developer

I am trying to publish my site from Visual Studios 2008 Web Developer SP1. I do first a clean build then I rebuild it.

I then go and try to publish it. I get one warning that seems to make it fail

```
Warning 1   Error updating JScript IntelliSense: C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\25YI099T\jquery-fds90[1]..js: Object doesn't support this property or method @ 2139:1    E:\Projects\Dir\Version 2\trunk\Site\Views\Shared\Site.Master   1   1
```

I don't understand why I am getting some Intellisense error when trying to publish it. I was able to publish my site yesterday just fine but now I get this and it seems to stop the publish.

Comment: Did you try removing the mentioned file in the Temporary Internet Files folder?

Comment: yea, thats what I would do too

Comment: Well I went to that folder. There was like 20 files in there non of them where that one. So I just deleted them anyways. But still complained so I went back to the folder again and nothing is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Close VS and delete the Bin and Obj folders.
2. Clear Browser History.
3. Clear out the following:

   - ClearFolder(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%") & "\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies")
   - ClearFolder(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%") & "\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Recent")
   - ClearFolder(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Local Settings\Application Data\ApplicationHistory")
   - ClearFolder(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies")
   - ClearFolder(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WINDIR%") & "\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files")

Comment: ("%APPDATA%") & "\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies". My %APPDATA% is "C:\Documents and Settings\amissico\Application Data". To find yours, type %appdata% in the Run dialog. Which most likely is, "C:\Users\bob\AppData"

Comment: If this doesn't work, I suspect you have added a variable, method, or other object, that conflicts when an existing variable, method, and so on.